# IE9 CORS - xdomain: Timeout waiting on iframe socket

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, xdomainrequest

I'm trying to do a CORS on ie9 using

ie9proxy.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script src="https://apiurl/Content/xdomain.min.js"></script>
```

"xdomain: Timeout waiting on iframe socket"

Hint: my ie9.proxy.html doesnt return the "X-Frame-Options" header

```
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="https://apiurl/Content/xdomain.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    xdomain.slaves({
     "https://apiurl": "/Content/ie9proxy.html"
    });
    </script>
  <![endif]-->
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Need to set up your Masters in proxy.html as below:

```
<script src="/dist/xdomain.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    xdomain.masters({
      "http://*.example.com": "/api/*.json"
    });
  </script>
```